# Export coxph summary from R to csv

Tags: r, dataframe, statistical-test, cox

How to export summary of cox_proportional hazard model from R to csv. I ran a test by function coxph.
by survival package
Now i want to export its summary to csv, how to do that.

```
c <- coxph(Surv(x~y)) 
summary(c)
```

Comment: Why .csv? Why not save it as an R object using saveRDS()?

Comment: Actually i first want to convert this summary into dataframe and then want to export it. I need it in csv

Comment: What do you want the structure of the df to be? n rows of 1 column???

Comment: There should be five columns that is.    coef        ,   exp(coef)  ,        se(coef)      ,     z      ,     p.
Rows should contain covariate x and y

Comment: `write.csv(summary(coxph(Surv(x~y)))$coefficients, "surv.csv")`

Comment: Thanks how to use this command for following Model<-lapply(split(DF, DF$Group),function(x) coxph(surv ~ x + y, data = DF))

Comment: I have editted the code a bit.

Comment: Does your code even work? You `split` the data by `$Group`, but then you completely ignore this by referencing `DF` again internally. (It really helps when code you insert here is either (1) code you have in your project that works, or (2) code that evidences a problem you are asking about. It appears neither is the case here, since this code will produce identical models for each `$Group`, and you would likely have seen that when you tried using this.)

Comment: Oh thanks for detecting the mistake. i didnot notice it. i was intended to run coph for my all groups by splitting my df. What should i refer it to if not DF?? Should it be DF$Group ?

Comment: `lapply(split(DF, DF$Group), function(GROUPDAT) coxph(surv ~ x + y, data = GROUPDAT))`

Comment: Did one of the answers below resolve your question? If so, please accept one (and optionally upvote some). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `?coxph` examples, I'll use:

```r
library(survival)
test1 <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
              status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
              x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0), 
              sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1)) 
mdl <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1)
mdl_summ <- summary(mdl)
mdl_summ
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), data = test1)
#   n= 7, number of events= 5 
# Warning: partial match of 'coef' to 'coefficients'
#     coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)
# x 0.8023    2.2307   0.8224 0.976    0.329
#   exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
# x     2.231     0.4483    0.4451     11.18
# Concordance= 0.667  (se = 0.167 )
# Rsquare= 0.144   (max possible= 0.669 )
# Likelihood ratio test= 1.09  on 1 df,   p=0.3
# Wald test            = 0.95  on 1 df,   p=0.3
# Score (logrank) test = 1.05  on 1 df,   p=0.3
```

If we look at the `str`ucture of that:

```r
str(mdl_summ)
# List of 14
#  $ call        : language coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), data = test1)
#  $ fail        : NULL
#  $ na.action   : NULL
#  $ n           : int 7
#  $ loglik      : num [1:2] -3.87 -3.33
#  $ nevent      : num 5
#  $ coefficients: num [1, 1:5] 0.802 2.231 0.822 0.976 0.329
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr "x"
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "coef" "exp(coef)" "se(coef)" "z" ...
#  $ conf.int    : num [1, 1:4] 2.231 0.448 0.445 11.18
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr "x"
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "exp(coef)" "exp(-coef)" "lower .95" "upper .95"
#  $ logtest     : Named num [1:3] 1.087 1 0.297
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "test" "df" "pvalue"
#  $ sctest      : Named num [1:3] 1.051 1 0.305
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "test" "df" "pvalue"
#  $ rsq         : Named num [1:2] 0.144 0.669
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "rsq" "maxrsq"
#  $ waldtest    : Named num [1:3] 0.95 1 0.329
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "test" "df" "pvalue"
#  $ used.robust : logi FALSE
#  $ concordance : Named num [1:2] 0.667 0.167
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "C" "se(C)"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "summary.coxph"
```

we see that there is a `coefficients` property we can use.

```r
class(mdl_summ$coefficients)
# [1] "matrix"
mdl_summ$coefficients
#                                 coef exp(coef)  se(coef)         z  Pr(>|z|)
# x                          0.7811819  2.184052 0.7975689 0.9794538 0.3273558
# survival::strata(sex)sex=1 0.9337832  2.544116 1.4081100 0.6631465 0.5072367
```

Since it's a `matrix`, we can use `write.csv` or `write.table` or any of its kin:

```r
write.csv(mdl_summ$coefficients, "surv.csv")
readLines("surv.csv")
# [1] "\"\",\"coef\",\"exp(coef)\",\"se(coef)\",\"z\",\"Pr(>|z|)\""                                   
# [2] "\"x\",0.802317911238375,2.23070551803984,0.822376639082848,0.975608830685119,0.329258346777417"
```

---

**Edit**: for your extension of doing this on a list of models.

```r
testlist <- list(a=test1, b=test1) # in your code, use `split(DF, DF$Group)`
mdls <- sapply(testlist, function(z) coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), data = z), simplify = FALSE)
mdls_summ <- lapply(mdls, summary)
lapply(mdls_summ, `[[`, "coefficients")
# $a
#        coef exp(coef)  se(coef)         z  Pr(>|z|)
# x 0.8023179  2.230706 0.8223766 0.9756088 0.3292583
# $b
#        coef exp(coef)  se(coef)         z  Pr(>|z|)
# x 0.8023179  2.230706 0.8223766 0.9756088 0.3292583
ign <- Map(function(dat, nm) write.csv(dat$coefficients, paste0(nm, ".csv")),
           mdls_summ, names(mdls_summ))
list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
# [1] "a.csv"    "b.csv"
```

Comment: Does  "mdl " here can be replaced by "Model " as i mentioned in my question??

Comment: No, but see my edit. If this does not address it, you really need to update your question, as it clearly and only says *"convert this into dataframe and then export that dataframe in csv"*, which is what the first portion of this answer does. Asking many unrelated questions in one SO-question is often not-good form, especially when you only *suggest* it in edited code.

Comment: Thanks anyways. Your time consuming effort is realy appreciated.

Comment: It will work when i will try that. for now No because i couldnot try it as my model got an error By correcting my code to Model<-lapply(split(DF, DF$Group),function(x) coxph(surv ~ x + y, data = x))
 I got an error  : Error in model.frame.default(formula = surv ~ x +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x'). My groups are not of same length. 
I might need to make a new question. totally screwed.

Comment: different-length groups should have nothing to do with it, since each model is run independently of the others. It might be because you reference a `data.frame` named `x` and a variable named `x` within it ... while I don't *know*, you might consider using a name other than `x` for your anonymous function dataset, perhaps the verbose `GROUPDAT` I used above (though no need for "yelling" ;-).

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use the function `tidy()` from **broom** package. Beware that in agreement with the *tidy* concept, columns are called in a different way w.r.t. the original summary of the Cox model.

You can read more about the package [here](https://broom.tidyverse.org).

```r
library(survival)
library(broom)

data("lung")

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
out = tidy(res.cox)

class(out)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
out
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   term  estimate std.error statistic p.value conf.low conf.high
#>   <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 sex     -0.531     0.167     -3.18 0.00149   -0.859    -0.203

write.csv(out, file = "~/Desktop/out.csv" )
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi. Can i use      out = tidy(res.cox) as out = tidy(Model) as per my question??

Comment: Aryh, in general, *no*. Inferring that you use `res.cox <- coxph(...)` (since you've never referenced that before), then realize that `res.cox` is a ***survival model*** or summary, i.e., class `"coxph"` or `"summary.coxph"`. In your edit, `Model` is class `list`. So no, nothing that operated on `res.cox` can operate as-is on `Model`. However, since each element of that list is likely to be `"coxph"` or `"summary.coxph"`, then you should be able to `lapply` over it just like you did for your models (and I have in my answer).